# How to scale along the local axis of an object?

Tags: mesh, transforms, vertices

I have an object which is rotated and not parallel to any axis. The picture shows how it looks if I scale four vertices along the y-axis. How can I extend the vertices along the local axis of the object?

[image: transform along global axes]

Comment: Did you rotate the object in object mode or edit mode?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you are in edit mode, select the desired vertices, press <kbd>S</kbd>, and then press either <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, or <kbd>Z</kbd> twice in a row.

After the first press it will transform along the global orientation as usual:

[image: default]

After the second press it will use the transform orientation selected in *3D view > header*, which is set to *local* by default:

[image: new]

If the orientation is set to *global* pressing the axis key (<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>) twice will still use the corresponding local axis.

This solution does not work if the vertices were rotated in edit mode. For that you may have to change the transform orientation to normal, and manually move the edges.

Comment: Not sure about the last bit, setting the transform orientation to *local* won't make it any different than if it was set to global. Did you mean *normal*?

Comment: Thank you for also including a solution when the object was rotated in edit mode.

Answer (score 10):

Change your transform orientation to *Local*, then you can use the *3D Manipulator* set to *Scale*.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In addition to iKlsR's answer, you can hit <kbd>Y</kbd> (or <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>) twice after hitting <kbd>G</kbd> (or <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd>), this will move along the object's local y, x, or z axis.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, G Z Z with the orientation set to *local* still moves vertices along the local axes for me.

Comment: @gandalf3 you're right!  I am pretty sure I remember doing *something* like that to transform along vertices' normals and I thought that was it.  I will do some experimenting and see if I can find it again, for now I edited that out.

Comment: Did you have the transform orientation set to *normal*?

Answer (score 8):

By default, all you have to do is press the axis key twice, e.g. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>.

[image]

In most cases, pressing the axis key twice will use the transform orientation specified in *3D view > Header*:

[image]

However there is one exception, as you can see in the gif above. Even though the transform orientation is set to *Global*, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> uses the *Local* orientation.

This is probably because pressing the axis key once (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>) *always* uses global axes, and it would be pointless to have a setting where <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> do the same thing.

---

Transform orientations are quite useful, and I recommend you have a look at the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations) if you haven't already.

Also note that you can define [custom orientations](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations#Custom_Orientations) with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: Btw, custom transform orientations can be deleted in *Transform Orientations` in `N`, and they are not updated when the source (like the face here, or axes, etc.) change. Many thanks @gandalf3 for the hint with custom orientations!

Answer (score 3):

You can change the transform handle space with the marked button:
[image]
Changing it to local will make the transform in the objects local space.

If you change it to normal it will force to Z-axis to be parallel to the face's normal which is useful if the mech is rotated in edit mode.

To access the different spaces using keyboard shortcuts, after selecting one from the drop down menu you might need to double press the constrain axis