# How can I extrude an edge along the local axis?

Tags: modeling, transforms

I have been searching for a solution and it should not be that hard. This is what I tried:

I created a cube and rotated it along the Z axis in object mode.
In edit mode I switched to the local transform orientation, which looks like this:
[image: Cube with local axis]
Which is exactly what I wanted.
Next I Extrude, and press X twice to presumably lock to the local X axis. However it ends up pointing in the wrong direction and in the bottom left it says "along normal X" which is not what I want:
[image]

How can I get blender to extrude along a local axis?
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that you have switched `Transform orientation` to `Local`? I do as you describe and it works for me even in `Global Transform` orientation, in `Local` too. Along normal `X` after pressing `X` twice I get if `Normal Transform Orientation` was selected.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply! sorry still getting used to stack exchange

Comment: I am not sure I changed the right thing. I changed it via Alt+Space. The changed value is visible in the first image at the bottom

Comment: What do you mean "right thing"? Yes, by pressing `Alt` + `Space` you change the `Transform Orientation`. I'll write a more depth answer now.

Comment: Actually, the answer to your question is already here - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18576/how-to-scale-along-the-local-axis-of-an-object?rq=1. So I think this question is possible duplicate.

Comment: Yes right, I wasn't the first to ask this qustion. However I followed this guide and end up with the normal axis instead of the local ones.

Comment: I am just going to try this on a fresh installation

Comment: @MrZak It works as described by the OP for me.. I definitely selected *local*. I guess the extrude and move operator ignores the selected transform orientation.

Comment: @gandalf3 I leave `Transform Orientation` by default on `Global`, extrude, press `X` twice and get extrusion by local axis. I didn't think it deserves full answer, I thought the OP simply selected `Normal` instead of `Global` option.

Comment: @MrZak Hm.. Perhaps it's a bug. What blender version/OS are you on? I tested it with 2.74 on Archlinux.

Comment: 2.74 / Win7 used. Just tested it now. Thought it should be like that, and`Normal` orientation I still can use, by switching to it

Answer (score 9):

This is because the *Extrude and Move* operator seems to always use *Normal* orientation.

To use the selected orientation (in this case *Local*), cancel the operator (<kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>), then press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> in order to use the normal *Move* operator:

[image]